# Decompiling an ashx file

Tags: ashx, decompiler

Hi has anybody been able to decompile one of these? I've managed to delete mine but found a compiled version in the temp asp.net folder.  Theres a lot of work in here and would really like to decompile it to get it back.  I've tried verious undelete tool and previous version options but no luck.  Many thanks in advance.